# Where to kill 11+ enemies in a row to get 1UP (without glitch/turtle trick)?

Tags: super-mario-bros

By killing multiple enemies in a row, you can get 100 - 200 - 400 - 500 - 800 - 1000 - 2000 - 4000 - 5000 - 8000 - 1UP - 1UP - 1UP ... (1UPs from the 11th enemy onwards) ([source](https://www.mariowiki.com/Point)).

I know there are several places where you can do the glitch/turtle trick to get infinite 1UPs this way (e.g. [a compilation of many such locations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lSfM7F-_2E), [4-1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11efH5CBPNg), [a very complicated way in 1-2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSL3og5--uE)).

However, without using this glitch/trick, where can one kill 11+ enemies in a row to get the 1UP this way?

Comment: Super Mario bros or new super Mario bros wii?

Comment: @Bratworst: The 1985 version (I think that's what the tag description says too).

Answer (score 1):

The [4-1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11efH5CBPNg) example you gave looks like a place where this is possible.  Use the green shell to box in the spinies, wait for Lakitu to generate 11+ spinies, then use the green shell to kill them all at once.

[World 8-2](https://www.mariowiki.com/World_8-2_(Super_Mario_Bros.)#Level_maps) is a better place for this, since it generates green turtles naturally, rather than requiring a glitch to turn a spiny into a green turtle.

Comment: This seems like it would work as long as OP is still allowing for a glitch that changes the spiked ones to red and green shells.

Comment: @JMac I just searched through the levels containing Lakitu, and found that 8-2 generates both Lakitus and green turtles legitimately.

Answer (score -4):

[From Super Mario Bros./Secrets Wiki](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros./Secrets)

1. Multiple Kills When enemies approach you in great numbers, get
   them in a row to score high points. Points will double (100, 200,
   400) for each enemy you get. Goombas are the best foes on which to
   test this technique.
2. Double Kills When you stomp on two enemies at a time, your score
   increases accordingly (100 + 400).
3. Kick and run When you use the stomped turtle to defeat the other
   enemies, your score will increase with each additional kill (500,
   800, 1000, 2000, 4000, 5000, 8000, 1-up). If you do this enough
   times, you'll get an extra life!
4. Other secret tactics There is a tactic called "wait and re-stomp"
   where you can wait for the turtle to revive after you stomp it, and
   then stomp it again for a high score. This "double stomp" tactic
   will change the 100 + 400 score into a 100 + 500 score.
5. Other variations of this tactic can also increase your score. One
   example is the "triple kill and kick." This high-level tactic will
   give you 100 + 200 + 400 + 1000 points. Depending on your skill, you
   can combine your attacks to increase your score. If you're going to
   do it, do it in style!

From what I gather, there may exist locations where you can piece together combos in order to reach the 11, or more, kills in order to achieve a 1UP. But why would you want to if you can just get 128 (the max) lives on World 1-1?

Comment: The question was specifically _where_ this could be done to get 11+ combos.

Comment: @JMac "From what I gather, there may exist locations where you can piece together combos in order to reach the 11, or more, kills in order to achieve a 1UP." It would behoove you to read the whole answer before trolling comments.

Comment: ... And the question specifically asks **where** those locations should be.  You determining that "there _may_ be locations where you can piece together combos in order to reach the 11, or more, kills in order to achieve a 1UP." doesn't actually address what OP asked.  It seems that they are quite aware that there _could be_ locations where this is the case.  You haven't provided those locations or shown that such a location doesn't exist, so you really didn't provide anything that answers the real question asked.

Comment: @JMac I took the time to try and answer the question. You're free to do the same. In the meantime, I recommend you upvote, downvote, no vote, and move along. That's the beauty of these forums. Enjoy your day.

Comment: I did downvote, and left a comment with my downvote explaining why.  You responded as if I didn't read it, when my comment explained what I felt was missing.  Because you didn't understand that, I felt the need to elaborate.  I would have downvoted, left the comment, and moved on, if you didn't accuse me of not reading or trolling.  Don't try to high-road me when I tried to follow regular procedure for an answer that doesn't answer the question.